# Enviar datos desde excel a sql server con VB.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, oledb

Buen día, 
Como dice el titulo, requiero enviar datos de un archivo de excel que se genera cada determinado tiempo.

Al momento he probado enviarlos usando OLEDB y un `sqlbulkcopy` pero ya que la tabla de excel y la de `SQL` no tienen el mismo formato requiero algún método que me permita modificar primero el formato del dataset (que lleno usando el `oledbdataadapter`) y luego enviarlo a la tabla `SQL` mediante el `sqlbulkcopy`

Los datos del excel tiene el siguiente formato

```
NOMBRE DATOS DATOS  DATOS DATOS 
NOMBRE DATOS DATOS  DATOS DATOS 
NOMBRE DATOS DATOS  DATOS DATOS 
FECHA1 HORA1 FECHA2 HORA2
```

Y el formato de la tabla de sql debería ser algo así;

```
NOMBRE DATOS DATOS DATOS DATOS FECHA1 HORA1 FECHA2 HORA2 
NOMBRE DATOS DATOS DATOS DATOS FECHA1 HORA1 FECHA2 HORA2 
NOMBRE DATOS DATOS DATOS DATOS FECHA1 HORA1 FECHA2 HORA2
```

Alguna recomendación de como hacer coincidir ambos formatos?

Les agradezco de antemano

Comment: tu formato de tabla no se entiende.

Comment: Gracias, he agregado una imagen para poder aclarar ambos formatos

Answer (score 0):

La solución mas sencilla es añadir cuatro nuevas columnas a tu tabla excel para incluir en cada fila su fecha1- hora1 - fecha2 - hora2 e incluir los valores oportunos.
Otra solución es crear un datatable que dependa de tu dataset (una vez cargados los datos), y mediante un bucle (para las filas) dentro de otro bucle (para las columnas) ir añadiendo los valores oportunos en unas nuevas columnas.
Hay más posibilidades, como por ejemplo no utilizar el SqlBulkCopy y en su lugar, añadir los registros a la antigua usanza (Insert into ......)
Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, al final lo que estoy intentando hacer es leer fila por fila añadiendo los campos de fechas y horas e insertarlos con el comando de sql (insert into.. )